# Dividing $8$ Children into $4$ teams of $2$ players each

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can you divide $8$ children into $4$ teams of $2$ players each?

My attempt:

$$ \binom{8}{2} \times \binom{6}{2} \times \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{2}{2}$$
$$ = 4 \times 7 \times 3 \times 5 \times 3 
\times 2 \times 1$$
$$ = 2520 $$

I got the answer by saying after the first team was chosen, one must subtract $2$ players and see in how many ways they can be combined. When I saw the memo, it stated the answer was $105$. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Here, the order of the teams themselves **does not** matter. If we choose, say, these teams:

$\{A,B\}, \{C,D\}, \{E,F\}, \{G,H\}$

that's exactly the same set of teams as these:

$\{C,D\}, \{A,B\}, \{G,H\}, \{E,F\}$

Because the order of the teams themselves does not matter, we must divide by 4! = 24, the number of different orders we can put the four teams in, because all 24 different orders are in fact the same set of teams.

The answer is thus $$ \frac{\binom{8}{2} \times \binom{6}{2} \times \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{2}{2}}{4!}$$
$$ = \frac{2520}{4!}$$
$$ = 105 $$

Comment: but I thought $\binom{n}{r}$ gives unordered elements. So I didn't have in mind to divide by $4!$

Comment: @AspiringMathlete ${n \choose r}$ gives unordered children of a team but does not give unordered teams.